# Variable within a object reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm getting the username from the input field and sending it as the parameter to the searchUser function. What it returns the username with a value of more objects.

so if I send 'daveeeeeed' in the input field and submit then it sends back

```
{"daveeeeeed":{"id":30155374,"name":"daveeeeeed","profileIconId":577,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1443840218000}}
```

so in my html document I'm trying to access res.'daveeeeeed'.name to print out the name from the request. But obviously {{ res.username.name }} isn't working. and in the javascript I cant use $scope.res = data.username.name.

My question is; how do I use a variable from a object? ex.

my goal
res.username.name //replace username with whatever was send in form

```
<form>
 <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" name="username" />
 <button ng-click="searchUser(username)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{{ res }}
```

here's the javascipt

```
 $scope.searchUser = function(username){

   $http.get('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + username + '?api_key=<key>').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.res = data;
    }).error(function(err) {
        $scope.res = "User not found";
    });
}
```

Comment: You can add `username` to `$scope` before making http call. Then you can access it in your DOM template like this `{{ res[username] }}`

Comment: thank you so much! I completely forgot about that, I feel so dumb!

Comment: Another option is to pull the key from the object, for example `Object.keys(data)[0]` (assuming only one key)

Comment: also try...  `res[username]["name"]` it should provide you what you want,

Comment: @Phil That's very simple to do but I usually avoid assuming things especially in code. It just increases readability of code. May be Personal Opinion. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding Answer from comment:

You can add username to $scope before making http call. Then you can access it in your DOM template like this {{ res[username] }}.

So Your code should look like this:

```
$scope.searchUser = function(username){

  $scope.username = username; // Notice this change

  $http.get('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + username + '?api_key=<key>').
    success(function(data) {
      $scope.res = data;
    }).error(function(err) {
      $scope.res = "User not found";
    }
  );
}
```

Template should look like this:

```
{{ res[username] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways -

**Method 1 :**
When returning the result, make the property of the object a static value (e.g. instead of sending *daveeeeeed*, send *user*).

```
{"user":{"id":30155374,"name":"daveeeeeed","profileIconId":577,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1443840218000}}
```

this way, you can display the name as :

```
<div> {{res.user.name}} </div>
```

**Method 2**
If you follow your own way,

```
<div> {{res[username].name}} </div>
```